# Put multiple pragma directives into one preprocessor define

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor, pragma

I need to push/pop several gcc diagnostics in my code. If that was needed in a single file I would do the following:

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic push
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat"
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wuninitialized"

...some code...

#pragma GCC diagnostic push
```

But I need this in multiple locations. So I want to have a #define or something similar. I thought about the following but c preprocessor does not allow #pragmas in #define.

```
#define PushWarnings \
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push \
    #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat" \
    #pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wuninitialized"
```

Is there a way of achieving this?

Comment: @EdHeal What do you mean by "fix"?

Comment: The code is *enabling* warnings (or rather, turning them into errors), not disabling them.

Comment: @melpomene - Compile the code so that all warnings are errors and not need to play around with bits of code not having that protection

Comment: Why don't you just fix the code so that those warnings don't fire?

Comment: @EdHeal Sometimes it's external code that you can't touch.

Comment: This is for external code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to do this. C99 introduced the `_Pragma` operator (also available in C++ since C++11).

A pragma such as

```
#pragma GCC diagnostic error "-Wformat"
```

can also be written as

```
_Pragma("GCC diagnostic error \"-Wformat\"")
```

The latter is not a `#` preprocessor directive, so it can be generated from macros:

```
#define PushWarnings \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic push") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic error \"-Wformat\"") \
    _Pragma("GCC diagnostic error \"-Wuninitialized\"")
```

Comment: Great. Happy to learn about _Pragma.